# Is there any way to get the original Host header value?

Tags: cloudflare

[This](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-) article says:

> With these added headers, Cloudflare passes on all HTTP headers as is
>   from the client to the origin.

However, there doesn't appear to be a standard way to get the `Host` from the original request.

Is there a way to do this, either via standard options or enterprise option?

Comment: Cloudflare doesn't normally modify the `Host` header -- whatever you receive at your origin should be exactly what was received in the original request. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: what about these other people who have the same issue https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-proxy-and-x-forwarded-host-header?

Comment: I really don't know why people are asking that. Cloudflare doesn't modify the `Host` header. Are you seeing a `Host` header that isn't what you expected?

Comment: Maybe it's because of some edge side code setup. I'll play around with a new site without such a config and will hopefully see that you're correct.